# How to automatically move specific MySQL tables from one machine to another?

Tags: mysql, database, migration, database-administration, sharding

I have a MySQL database with tables in the form of `"shard_0"`, `"shard_1`", `"shard_2"`, etc.

I want to add another DB server and move the even-numbered shards (`"shard_0"`, `"shard_2"`, `"shard_4"`, ...) to the new machine.

How do I do that? There are many tables so ideally I wouldn't have to type out each table name individually but do something automatically.

Thanks

Comment: Bravo for recognizing that this is is an excellent opportunity for scripting; a definable and repeatable process

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can dump the tables like this

```
#!/bin/bash

DATABASE="YourDatabaseName"
TNAME=shard_
TVAL="0"

while [ $TVAL -lt 10 ]
do
     mysqldump -u user -pPassword "$DATABASE" "$TNAME$TVAL" > "$TNAME$TVAL.sql"
    TVAL=$[$TVAL+2]
done
```

You'll end up with files shard_0.sql ... shard_8.sql. Transfer them to the new machine however you want but something like the code below should work

```
for FILE in `ls shard_*.sql`
do
   scp "$FILE" user@newhost:"$FILE"
done
```

Then import the files into your database on the new machine

```
for FILE in `ls shard_*.sql`
do
   mysql -u user -pPassword YourDataBaseName <"$FILE"
done
```

Answer (score 2):

Syntax will vary depending on what language you want to use, but since you want the even-numbered tables, you'll iterate through the tables in the database and add a conditional statement (if) to check the name using the modulus operator (remainder of a divide, in this case dividing by 2) to determine whether or not it is an even number.  If it's even, do the mysql dump, otherwise skip.

in Pseudocode:

- for each table in database
- parse out the number from the table name

  - if %2 == 0                # %2 is "modulus 2 equals 0"; "modulus is sometimes called "mod"

    - {mysqldump [options];}
  - end if
- next
- rsync/scp to other server

Then on the other server, import your dumpfiles.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following shell script:

```
table="shard_"
for i in `seq 0 10` ; do
        r=`expr $i % 2`
        if [ $r -eq 0 ] ; then
                table_name="$table$i"
                echo "Exporting Table: $table_name"
                mysqldump -u user -pPass database $table_name > "$table_name.sql"
                # Here, you can copy/transfer the file
        fi
done
```